# Connecting an 8 pin connector to my 4 pin CPU?

Tags: cpu, power-supply

I just bought a PSU which has a 4+4 pin for the CPU. I thought that my CPU has 4 pin connector but when i removed it i realised there were another 4 on the left covered by a small plastic piece.

[image]

My question is:

Should I just stick to 4 pin? Is it safe if I connect all 8 pins into the CPU? Will it have any advantage over just 4 pins?

This is my motherboard data:

[image]

Comment: there's the possibility that other mobos in the series need all 8, but lower-end ones don't. Without knowing what mobo that is a pure guess.

Comment: What motherboard?

Comment: I have added the mother board information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your power supply has both 4-pin connectors, **connect them**.  You won't hurt anything if your configuration doesn't require them, but you *might* hurt something if you don't connect them but need to.

This forum [post](http://vip.asus.com/forum/view.aspx?board_id=1&model=P7H55-M%20PRO&id=20110519121252503&page=1&SLanguage=en-us) on Asus's website confirms the motherboard will function even if only the exposed 4-pin connector is connected to the power supply, but leaves open the possibility some configurations might require the second connection.

**The second 4-pin connector is probably meant to provide additional power needed by some high-end CPUs.** This [post](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/293265-28-should-connector-core) on tomshardware.com states the extra power is needed when running dual processors or a single CPU that draws more than 125 watts. The first isn't the case with this motherboard because it only supports a [single](http://www.cnet.com/products/asus-p7h55-m-pro-motherboard-micro-atx-lga1156-socket-h55-series/specs/) CPU, but the second comes into play if, for example, you're running something like the *Intel® Core™ i7-975 Processor Extreme Edition* processor which needs a whopping [130 watts](http://ark.intel.com/products/37153/Intel-Core-i7-975-Processor-Extreme-Edition-8M-Cache-3_33-GHz-6_40-GTs-Intel-QPI).

Comment: What is the advantage of using 8 pins?

Comment: More power capacity, obviously. May be required for high-end CPUs and/or overclocking.

Comment: @Dbugger - ever seen the pins burn on an older P4 system when they first started requiring the secondary power connector? More pins - more current capacity, or less current per pin when running at lower power requirements. We solved the burnt pin problem by stripping the wires and soldering them direct to the motherboard.